# Is there a way to cancel a mysql query in Azure or AWS properly?

Tags: java, mysql, azure, amazon-rds

It is very useful to define a query timeout in your application to prevent any long-running select queries that can impose excessive pressure on the database. You can find more information about it at https://vladmihalcea.com/query-timeout-jpa-hibernate/

Setting this timeout is quite straightforward, but making it work for Azure or AWS is, as I see it, impossible. The reason for this is that running the KILL command, which is exactly what the JDBC driver does, is not allowed in Azure nor AWS: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/8.0/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/StatementImpl.java#L310

Both Azure and AWS require a stored procedure to terminate a query.
For Azure, you need to use `CALL mysql.az_kill_query(:id:)`, and for AWS, you need to use `CALL mysql.rds_kill_query(:id)`.

I know there is a way to set a statement timeout server-side, but I prefer to have this in place client-side as well.

**Update:**
Solved after migrating from Azure Single Server to Azure Flexible Server.

Answer (score 0):

I dispute your assumption that it is a common best practice to define query timeouts. That's an opinion at best.

I would claim that the *proper* solution is to make sure queries are optimized before you run them in production, so they don't need to be timed out.

If you need to run super complex reporting queries, which take minutes or hours even with all the optimizations you can make, then don't run these queries on an OLTP database instance where they could take resources you need for ongoing transactions. Instead, run heavy-duty reporting queries on a replica instance or a data warehouse.

If you do need to time out queries on your OLTP instance, you can set a session variable `max_execution_time` (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_execution_time).

This only applies to read-only SELECT statements not run inside stored procedures.